# unable to install gnu parallel in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, gnu-parallel

Travis CI is using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to install GNU Parallel on it and used to be able to with `sudo apt-get install parallel` but now am not able to. What do I need to do? Do I need to compile it from scratch now?

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel is a perl script. It does not need compiling and is extremely easy to install:

```
wget pi.dk/3
bash -x 3
```